# Regex input pattern for 3 char string followed by a space and then an integer

Tags: html, regex, validation

I have this pattern `.*?[a-z]([a-z])([a-z])([a-z]).*?(\s+)(\d+)` from some online generator but it's not working.

I need pattern which allows:

"minimum 3 char length string, next single space, and next minimum 1 char integer" [abc 1] or the same but in different order "minimum 1 char integer, next single space, and next minimum 3 char length string" [3 gtf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\d+\s\w{3,}|\w{3,}\s\d+
```

It either matches:

1. One or more digits (`\d+`), followed by a single whitespace (`\s`), followed by three or more word characters (`\w{3,}`) (this is [a-zA-Z0-9], you can replace this part with [a-zA-Z] if you'd like).
2. Three or more word characters (this is [a-zA-Z0-9], you can replace this part with [a-zA-Z] if you'd like), followed by a single whitespace, followed by one or more digits.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tG5nV8/3)

Answer (score 1):

The following expression should do what you describe:

```
[a-z]{3,}\s\d+|\d+\s[a-z]{3,}
```

Some notes:

1. The `{3,}` construct allows you to specify repetitions within a given range. In general, it's `{min,max}`, but you can leave out either min or (as here) max to have an open-ended range. You can also specify an exact number of repeats by specifying a single number, e.g. `{99}`.
2. The expression is essentially two complete expressions switched with alternation. Regular expressions don't allow you to say "exactly these things, in any order".
3. I've used `[a-z]` to match the characters in the non-numeric part, as this is what you did in your original example.