# HTML5 Form Validation Pattern

Tags: regex, html, validation

I'm dabbling with Form Validation using HTML5 patterns. I would like for my input field to allow any combination of only the following characters.

```
, @ – - . ; / ' : ( ) # a-z A-Z 0-9 space
```

I've been trying to create the pattern to accomplish this. I thought I came up with a solution using regexr.com. On that site my pattern works great, but when implemented in my form everything shows up as an invalid entry. For example 'Test' is invalid 'Test D'luxe' is invalid, 'Company Test #1' is invalid, etc.

[My Results on RegExr](http://regexr.com/3d1ff)

Here is the pattern I've come up with:

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z[\d\[\-\.\_,\(\)\#\:\;\'\/]"
```

I've looked at a few other stack overflow posts such as

- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353792/html5-form-pattern-validation)
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619428/html5-form-validation-pattern-alphanumeric-with-spaces)
- [And This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970438/html5-input-pattern)

but I've been unable to piece together what I'm doing incorrectly.
I would appreciate any help. I'm very new to this so I'm open to any and all feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should allow 0+ characters by adding a `*` quantifier at the end, replace `'` with `\x27` and get rid of the redundant escaping:

```
pattern="[-,@–.;/\x27:()#a-zA-Z0-9 ]*"
```

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input value="-,@–.;/':()#azAZ09 " pattern="[-,@–.;/\x27:()#a-zA-Z0-9 ]*" title="Please enter allowed characters only."/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.